# How to deploy pods described in yaml files using client-go?

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go

Without using kubectl, I want to use client-go to deploy deployment/services described in yaml files. Which approach is the  best: clientset, rest or dynamic? I do not want to parse yaml file and set every attributes of Deployment objects in clientset. So is there a way just load yaml config(maybe convert to json format) and apply it directly ?

Comment: ok, I find the solution in this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47116811/client-go-parse-kubernetes-json-files-to-k8s-structures/47139247?r=SearchResults#47139247

Comment: Possible duplicate of [client-go: parse kubernetes json files to k8s structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47116811/client-go-parse-kubernetes-json-files-to-k8s-structures)